# package `bumpalo v3.15.2` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.73.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.72.0-dev

Tags: solana-cli, cargo, build-bpf, build-sbf

package `bumpalo v3.15.2` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.73.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.72.0-dev
Either upgrade to rustc 1.73.0 or newer, or use
cargo update -p bumpalo@3.15.2 --precise ver
where `ver` is the latest version of `bumpalo` supporting rustc 1.72.0-dev

cargo-build-sbf --version
solana-cargo-build-sbf 1.18.2
platform-tools v1.39
rustc 1.72.0

can anyone explain the exact reason for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to update your solana tools version, you can do `solana-install init 1.16.23` or whatever (I think latest is `1.17.9` as of now).

When you build it uses the version of rustc included with Solana not the one installed on your system.

Answer (score 1):

If at all you are using solana_sdk or solana_program_test on onchain programs, they are the culprits, just delete them from Cargo.toml and from your code. I nuked my OS thrice before I figured it out.