# Unable to Retrieve External Public Address in libp2p Swarm Events

Tags: rust

I am working on a Rust project using the libp2p library to create a peer-to-peer network. I have configured my swarm to listen on all interfaces using the following code:

```
let listen_address_udp = format!("/ip4/0.0.0.0/udp/{}/quic-v1", port);
swarm.listen_on(listen_address_udp.parse()?)?;
let listen_address_tcp = format!("/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/{}", port);
swarm.listen_on(listen_address_tcp.parse()?)?;
```

However, when reading swarm events, I am unable to retrieve the external public address that my node is listening on. The code for reading swarm events is as follows:

```
loop {
    select! {
        _ = sig_term_handler.recv() => {
            trigger_message = !trigger_message;
        },
        event = swarm.select_next_some() => match event {
            SwarmEvent::Behaviour(MyBehaviourEvent::Gossipsub(gossipsub::Event::Message {
                propagation_source: peer_id,
                message_id: id,
                message,
            })) => {
                println!(
                    "Received'{}' with id: {id} from peer: {peer_id}, Size :{}",
                    String::from_utf8_lossy(&message.data), message.data.len()
                )
            },
            SwarmEvent::NewListenAddr { address, .. } => {
                println!("Local node is listening on {address}");
            }
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}
```

The output I receive only shows the local addresses where my node is listening, such as:

```
Local node is listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/8082
Local node is listening on /ip4/172.24.181.240/tcp/8082
```

I have tried pinging and opening port 8082 for TCP on all nodes, but I still cannot determine if my local node is publicly listening or not. What should be the external public address I expect to see in the `SwarmEvent::NewListenAddr` event? Any suggestions or insights into resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [package \`bumpalo v3.15.2\` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.73.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.72.0-dev](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/10457/package-bumpalo-v3-15-2-cannot-be-built-because-it-requires-rustc-1-73-0-or-ne)

Comment: Seems like you got unlucky and tried to use 1.18.3 while it was being created. You can try again now

Comment: Then you can try 1.18.2